# Shift a polyline which hides another one on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing transport lines that are overlapping: two lines are going through the same road.

```js
      var routePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: polylinePoints,
```

As one line hides the other, I would like to shift one of these lines to make the two lines visible on the network.
I was wondering if it was possible to move a polyline as "one whole shape"?
because when I use the options: draggable:true, editable:true I get the opportunity to redraw the polyline "point by point", and as you have understood, it is not what I would like to do.

Thanks.

Comment: You could iterate on Polyline coords and add to each of this a little shift

Comment: I had thought about that, but it will be tiresome, because it will be hard to guess the accurate shift(trial and error). I was wondering if there was a way to do it on the map as it is the case with the markers.
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(stop[currentStopId]['lat'], stop[currentStopId]['lon']),
draggable:true,
map: map
 });

Comment: For the polyline no!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation.Do you see a concurrent suggestion to that which is to add a shift to the polyline coords?

Comment: I have posted an answer for a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way (it is only a suggestion  not tested ):

manage  the polyline by click event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'click',      function(line) {
    var coord = line.getPath();
    var newCoords 
    var numCoord = coord.length;
    for (i = 0; i <  numCoord; i++) {
          newCoord[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(coord[i].lat + yourShiftY, coord[i].lng + yourShiftX);
    }

    line.setPath(newCoord);

});
```